Time dilation of distant stars changed by walking or standing still, paradox?
Disclaimer, using generalized numbers here to illustrate the question, not to be mathematically accurate.
Based on my understanding, if you were standing still vs. walking towards a distant star, say millions of light years away, the miniscule time dilation difference is enough to change the age you see that distant start at.
For instance, the person walking towards the star that's millions of light years away would see the star as 2 days older than the person standing still.
I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding something, because this seems to generate two paradoxes.
Setup: Observing the age of that star is observing the photons, which are travelling at the speed of light. What if that star emitted a gamma ray burst directed at the observer a million light years ago. The gamma rays travel at the speed of light. The person walking would see the star as two days older, which means he would be hit by the gamma ray burst 2 days sooner than the person standing still.
Paradox #1, the walking person gets hit by a gamma ray burst, and then stops walking. Time dilation now shows the star as 2 days younger, before the gamma ray burst, so he was never hit.
Paradox #2. The person walking walks right past a standing person at the moment they get hit by the gamma ray burst. The standing person would instantly see the walking person get killed, even though from his frame of reference the star has not yet emitted the gamma ray burst yet. That information of the future gamma ray burst now travelled faster than the speed of light, as he knows information about his future.
This one's been keeping me up at night for a while now.

"Observing the age of that star is observing the photons, which are travelling at the speed of light" is wrong. In relativity "observing" means "assigning coordinates to" not "seeing with one's eyes". This is a very common confusion amongst people new to relativity.

That may be true, but the premise that the walking observer sees light from the distance start 2 days older than the standing observer due to time-dilation still holds true. Or at least this portion I'm just refencing directly from several physics influencers (pbs spacetime, sabine, fermilab, etc,)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rietdijk%E2%80%93Putnam_argument#Andromeda_paradox

You are confusing at least three different effects, and overestimating two of them.
Firstly, time dilation does not increase with distance. It is a function of relative velocity, and is entirely negligible at walking pace.
Secondly, assuming the person walking and the person standing still are more or less next to each other, they will see exactly the same photons. The person walking (assuming they are walking towards the star) will see radiation from the star blue-shifted, but again at walking speed the effect will be entirely negligible.
The effect that does increase steadily with distance is the relativity of simultaneity. What that means is that the person walking and the person standing still have different answers for the question what time it is 'now' on the distance star? If the star is sufficiently far away, then yes, the difference can be two days, so that for one person it might 'now' be Tuesday on the distant star and for the other it might 'now' be Thursday. However, that makes no difference to what they see, as they are both receiving the same photons, photons which left the star a very long time ago.

What you literally see is unchanged by your speed (except for the Doppler effect, which is negligible at walking speed). All that changes are the coordinates you assign to the distant events. The stationary person and moving person both experience the gamma ray burst at the same time, but one might say it happened 1,000,000 years ago and the other says it was 1,000,001 years ago. Similarly they differ on what is happening "now" in the distant galaxy, but they won't actually experience that until a million years (or so) have passed.
If the descriptions you've seen of this situation (called the Andromeda Paradox) seem to say otherwise, it's probably because you're confused by the use of the verb "observes", which in relativity is often used to describe the situation one deduces after correcting for the finite speed of light.
